# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString is not working as intended

Tags: vb.net, httprequest, query-string

I need to get collection of HTTP query names and values. I am using this code:

```
Dim query = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/globalmap/clanbattles/?application_id=b72a008042b0afa92aa44bd9fc20f5d9&clan_id=500061064"
Dim nameValuePairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query)
```

I am expecting to get (name:value):

> application_id:b72a008042b0afa92aa44bd9fc20f5d9
>   clan_id:500061064

But I get:

> https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/globalmap/clanbattles/?application_id:b72a008042b0afa92aa44bd9fc20f5d9
>   clan_id:500061064

Is this bug in .NET Framework 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot that you must pass Query part, not whole Uri...

```
Dim nameValuePairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(New Uri("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/globalmap/clanbattles/?application_id=b72a008042b0afa92aa44bd9fc20f5d9&clan_id=500061064").Query)
```